# DynamicProxyFactory error with received data size

Tags: web-services, wcf, c#-4.0, reflection, dynamic-proxy

I use a dynamicproxyfactory in order to call any webservice by a wsdl string path. Unfortunalty, when a webservice answers a lot of data, an exception is raised :

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   Le quota de taille maximale autorisée
>   pour les messages entrants (65536) a
>   été dépassé. Pour augmenter le quota,
>   utilisez la propriété
>   MaxReceivedMessageSize sur l'élément
>   de la liaison appropriée. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException:
>   Le quota de taille maximale autorisée
>   pour les messages entrants (65536) a
>   été dépassé. Pour augmenter le quota,
>   utilisez la propriété
>   MaxReceivedMessageSize sur l'élément
>   de la liaison appropriée.    --- Fin
>   de la trace de la pile d'exception
>   interne ---
>
> Server stack trace:     à
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
>   à
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.GetMessageBuffer()
>   à
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream
>   inputStream)    à
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&
>   requestException)    à
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    à
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    à
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    à
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    à
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)    à
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     à
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    à
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    à
>   IWS_MG.ProceedOperation(String xmlIn) 
>   à WS_MGClient.ProceedOperation(String
>   xmlIn)}

This exception means the maxsize is 65536, and the data size received is larger.

Anybody knows how change the maxsize ?

For information, this is my code :

```
try
                    {
                        // Factory Creation with WCF WSDL address
                        DynamicProxyFactory factory = new DynamicProxyFactory(sServiceWsdl);

                        // Solution test which doesn't work    
                        foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in factory.Endpoints)
                        {

                            Binding binding = endpoint.Binding;

                            XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
                            myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
                            myReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
                            myReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
                            myReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
                            myReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;

                            binding.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding, myReaderQuotas, null);
                        }

                        // Proxy Creation with Contract's name
                        DynamicProxy proxy = factory.CreateProxy(sContract);

                        XElement XmlIN = XElement.Parse(sXmlIN);

                        // Method call with parameters
                        XElement XmlOUT = XElement.Parse((string)proxy.CallMethod(sMethod, XmlIN.ToString()));

                        sXmlOUT = XmlOUT.ToString(SaveOptions.None);

                        proxy.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        sXmlOUT = new XElement("ALL_XML_OUT", new XElement("APP_TRX", sAppTrx), new XElement("WS_RC", 1), new XElement("ERROR_MESS", e.Message)).ToString(SaveOptions.None);
                    }
```

Comment: Maybe the solution is to create dynamicly WebReference and not ServiceReference but I didn't find any tutorial on the web

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the DynamicProxy library but the binding object should have a [MaxReceivedMessageSize property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) as in the basicHttpBinding. You need to set it to a value greater than 64K that is appropriate for your application. Also, make sure that the **service** is configured with the same value for the binding the client is calling on.

Comment: Check the code, I already did that :
myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;

Comment: Sorry, I got the property names confused, I updated the answer for the other thing you should also check :)

Comment: Yes, the two need to be in synch.

Comment: It's a problem with the client because if I register the webservice as webreference, it's work. But the soft would become useless because it shouldn't call any webservice anymore, only those will have the same interface / contract.

Comment: WCF allows setting the MaxReceivedMessageSize property of a binding in code so there should be a place in the DynamicProxy API to set the value. It would be wherever the API allows access to the underlying WCF binding.

Comment: I tried to find a way, but I didn't found anything about this problem.... anybody ?